# How may I fill a particular box with a color in matplotlib?

Tags: python

In a plot, I wish to **fill** a square **box** specified by

```
LeftTop = (1, 2); LeftBottom = (1, 1);
RightTop = (2, 2); RightBottom = (2 ,1);
```

**with red** color.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

See the reference:  http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle

And here:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

LeftBottom = (1, 1)
rect = mpatches.Rectangle(LeftBottom, 2, 1, color = "red")
```

Hope it helps!